# docker image run authentication required

Tags: image, authentication, docker

Please help me to add credential in docker image. So if some try to enter in image it ask for credential.

Scenario - 
Let say I downloaded a ubuntu image from official site, I did some changes and created a new image ubuntu-myapp.

Now no one can enter in ubuntu to copy or change my code. without provided credential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create a Dockerfile by adding credentials to the root user and change to a different user** something like this.

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY raghu/varibale.py /root
#create password for the root user. echo "USERNAME:NEWPASSWORD" | chpasswd
RUN echo "root:raghu" | chpasswd
#create a different user for public access.
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash raghu
#change to the new user
USER raghu
```

Build the docker image from the Dockerfile. This **Docker image can be run by anyone but the script can be executable only by the root user**.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
auth                2.0                 0c15c8ef5594        7 seconds ago       112MB
```

Let's execute the Docker image and check if the user can access the file without the root password:

```
$ docker run -it auth:2.0 /bin/bash
raghu@17b003083ff7:/$ ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
raghu@17b003083ff7:/$ cd root
bash: cd: root: Permission denied
raghu@17b003083ff7:/$ su -
Password: 
root@17b003083ff7:~# ls
varibale.py
root@17b003083ff7:~# pwd
/root
root@17b003083ff7:~# exit
logout
raghu@17b003083ff7:/$ exit
exit
```

The **file cannot be executed even with privileged option unless provided with root password**:

```
$ docker run -it --privileged auth:2.0 /bin/bash
raghu@3886fb3950f8:/$ ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
raghu@3886fb3950f8:/$ cd root
bash: cd: root: Permission denied
raghu@3886fb3950f8:/$ su -
Password: 
root@3886fb3950f8:~# ls
varibale.py
root@3886fb3950f8:~# exit
logout
raghu@3886fb3950f8:/$ exit
exit
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your docker file, you need to set root user with password.

> echo 'newpassword' |passwd root --stdin

and make sure that all folder just has got root access to modify any content.